# SQLiteCursorLoader does not refresh data in Activity after saving in background thread in Fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursorloader

Here is my situation. My app is intended to report different activities. To be concrete I have a form (Fragment) where user can enter the data and save it. After that user can preview the form (Activity). PreviewActivity uses the SQLiteCursorLoader. Being in PreviewActivity user can switch to FormActivity in order to change previously entered data in Form Fragment. it is called by startActivityForResult(). After that a saving process begins and it relies on calling AsyncTask which handles inserting/updating into database in doInBackground() method. UI Thread follows further instructions, sets Result in FormActivity and closes FormActivity. In PreviewActivity in onActivityresult() method I call restartLoader() method on LoaderManager. My situation is quite different I think because I need to restart several loaders (9 actually) - it is a result of my database architecture. After each load in onLoadFinished() method I call my controller to update different sections of view. The problem is that data is not refreshed. Below some sample code to visualize the problem:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, FormActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE);
```

After filling form in FormActivity:

```
save() {
 new MyAsyncTaskFormSaver().execute(); //saving data
 finish();
}
```

Again in PreviewActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {//here I also use restartLoader()
    super.onCreate();
    restartLoader();
}    

void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        restartLoaders();
    }
    }
void restartLoaders() {
   final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

    loaderManager.restartLoader(1, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(2, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(3, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(4, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(5, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(6, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(7, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(8, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(9, null, this);
    loaderManager.restartLoader(10, null, this);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    switch(loader.getId()) {

        case 1:
                mController.populateView1(data, PreviewActivity.this);
            break;
        case 2:

                mController.populateView2(data, PreviewActivity.this);
            break;
        case 3:
                mController.populateView3(data, PreviewActivity.this);
             break;
        case 4:
                mController.populateView4(data, findViewById(R.id.view4));
            break;
        case 5:
                mController.populateView5(data,findViewById(R.id.view5));
            break;
        case 6:
                mController.populateView6(data, findViewById(R.id.view6));
            break;
        case 7:
                mController.populateView7(data, findViewById(R.id.view7));
            break;
        case 8:
                mController.populateView8(data, findViewById(R.id.view8));
            break;
        case 9:
                mController.populateView9(data, findViewById(R.id.view9), getSupportFragmentManager());
            break;
        case 10:
                mController.populateView10(data, findViewById(R.id.view10), getSupportFragmentManager());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(TAG + ": unknown data Id in onLoadFinished method. Id = " + loader.getId());
    }
```

In several populate Methods I need SupportfragmentManager in order to show dialogs if user clicks for button which shows photo preview but it is not relevant.

My question is:

Why data does not refresh after saving and switching to PreviewActivity?

I read many howTo-articles and  but most of them concern the situations with one CursorLoader used in adapter in ListView.

Am I using SQliteCursorLoader incorrectly?

I tried destroyingLoader in onStop() but nothing. Maybe it is not the CursorLoader.

Maybe I use AsyncTask  incorrectly?

Any information, help, criticism, and especially how to sove it, much appreciated.

Edit:

Ok, I found out that loader will update data provided that it inserts/updates/replaces/removes data by itself. So another question raises:

how to exchange loader between activities?

Ok, here I found the answer: 
[Global Loader (LoaderManager) for reuse in multiple Activities / Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045543/global-loader-loadermanager-for-reuse-in-multiple-activities-fragments)